# $X \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0,\sigma ^2) \implies \frac{X}{\sqrt{S_n ^2}} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I want to check the following $X \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0,\sigma ^2) \implies \frac{X}{\sqrt{S_n ^2}} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1)$

I know $S_n ^2$ is a consistent estimator for the variance, but how can I use that to deduce anything like the above?

Comment: $\frac{X}{\sqrt{S_n^2}} = \frac{X}{\sigma} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{S_n^2}}$. Can you see what to do now?

Comment: $\dfrac{X}{\sqrt{S_n^2}} = f(X, S_n^2),$ $(X, S_n^2) \to (X, \sigma^2)$ weakly and $f$ is continuous, can you see what to do now?